# Self-Attention Explainability of the Output Score Matrix

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, matrix, neural-network, attention-model

I am learning about attention models, and following along with Jay Alammar's amazing blog tutorial on The [Illustrated Transformer](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/). He gives a great walkthrough for how the attention scores are calculated, but I get a bit lost at a certain point, and am not seeing how the attention score `Z` matrix he explains is used to interpret strength of associations between different words within an input sequence.

He mentions that given some input matrix `X`, with shape `N x D`, where `N` is the number of elements in an input sequence, and `D` is the input dimensionality, we multiply `X` with three separate weight matrices of shape `D x d`, where `d` is some lower dimensionality that represents the projected space of the query, key, and value matrices:
[image]

The query and key matrices are dotted, and then divided by a scaling factor usually the square root of the projected dimensionality, and then run through a softmax function. This produces a weight matrix of size `N x N`, which is multiplied by the value matrix to get an output `Z` of shape `N x d`, which Jay says

> That concludes the self-attention calculation. The resulting vector is
>   one we can send along to the feed-forward neural network.

The screenshot from his blog for this calculation is below:
[image]
However, this is where I'm confused. `Z` is `N x d`. However, I don't particularly understand what I'm supposed to do with this matrix from an interpretability sense, and as far as I understand, for a particular sequence element (ie. the word `cats` in the sequence `I love pets, especially cats`), self-attention is supposed to score other parts of the sequence high when it is relevant or strong associated with that word embedding. However, I'd expect then that `Z` is `N x N`, so I could say that I can select the `Z[i,j]` and say for the `i-th` word in the sequence, the `j-th` word relates or associates with it this or that much.

**In fact, wouldn't it make much more sense to use only the softmax output of the weights (without multiplying them by the value matrix), since it already is `N x N`? In essence, how is Jay determining the strength of these associations in this particular sequence with the word `it`?** 
[image]

This is an `N` by `1` relationship he is showing - there are `N` values that correspond with the strength of association to the word `it`.

Comment: Hi @Yu Chen, interesting question! Could you find an answer yet?